# How to insert multiple items on the same line

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wanted to ask how I could put multiple elements on the same line: label, boxview, label`

```xml
    <Grid Margin="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label x:Name="utente" Padding="10, 0, 0, 0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Profilo + icona" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White"></Label>
                <Label x:Name="lblClick" Padding="0, 0, 10, 0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Logout" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="White">
                </Label>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
            </Grid>
```

[image]

Like this it's okay, only I would like to remove the gap between the horizontal line and the vertical line, I have already tried with the padding and with the margin, but I have not obtained results

Answer (score 1):

By default the Grid separates the objects using a Spacing value of 6

Reducing the space between objects in a grid using [RowSpacing or ColumnSpacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#space-between-rows-and-columns) (it will affect all the grid). Of course, one will affect space between rows and the other between columns.

In your case you want to reduce the space between the rows.

```
<Grid Margin="0" RowSpacing="0">
            ....Rest of your code...
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the vertical white line in your picture, it is due to the use of
`<BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions=" FillAndExpand"></BoxView>`.

For the horizontal lines in your picture, it depends on the layout influence outside the Grid.